# Formula to count layers of damascus steel

Tags: exponentiation

- I have an ***n*** layer (forge-welded) steel billet.
- I fold it ***i*** times.
- The total layer count doubles with each fold.

How can i express this with a simple formula?

Is it simply: ***n*(2^i)*** ?

---

#### For example

13 layers folded 5 times: ***13*(2^5)=416***

Comment: Sounds right to me.

Comment: @saulspatz or is it ***n\*(2^(i-1))***